# debounceTime() over API calls using Rxjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, rxjs

I am trying to understand rxjs and got stuck at a `debounceTime(n /* ms */)` experiment.

> public debounceTime(dueTime: number, scheduler: Scheduler): Observable
>
> Emits a value from the source Observable only after a particular time span has passed without another source emission.
>
> [source](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-debounceTime)

My code:

```
function fakeAPI() {
    return new Rx.Observable(observer => {

    const root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'

    $.ajax({
      url: root + '/posts/1',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
      observer.next(data)
    }).fail(function(err) {
      observer.error(err)
    })

    return ()=>{
      observer.complete()
      console.log('unsubscribed!')
    }
  })
}

const fakeObserver = fakeAPI()

$('#buttonText').click(()=>{

   fakeObserver
     .debounceTime(10000)
     .subscribe(() => {
        return {
          next(item) {
             console.log('received: ', item.id)
          },
          error(err) {
             console.log('error:', err)
          },
          complete() {
             console.log('completed!')
          }
       }
   }());  
})
```

My expectation: Even with N number of clicks in the given amount of time, the API call would only be made once. Instead, it seems like it waits for the given time and then all the N clicks result in an API call.

What am I doing wrong?

As per the docs, debounceTime(n) is supposed to discard previous pending delayed emissions if a new value arrives on the source.

Here is a [JSBin link](https://jsbin.com/rubazalowo/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per the docs, debounceTime(n) is supposed to discard previous pending delayed emissions if a new value arrives on the source.

It's true but on each click:

1. You create new subscription
2. It calls api
3. Api returns result
4. `debounceTime` waits 10s (nothing happens because `observerable` returned by `fakeObserver` emits only once)
5. You log the result

You need to convert your clicks in observable to implement what you want:

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('buttonText'), 'click')
```

Check [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/pekagoboco/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: I am not clear with the 4th point, what I observed was, it (my code) behaves exactly like delay(n). Is it because if `.subscribe` call is made over an observable it will be treated as a fresh subscription? so if I have an observer observing the API call value, would I be able to get same results?

Comment: @Amresh Venugopal, Please rephrase, I do not understand

Comment: If the .subscribe call is made once to the observer, only then would the debounce(n) work once per N clicks for given n seconds, as per my expectation?

Comment: @Amresh Venugopal, Basically yes. `debounce` should be used against `observable` that emits multiple values then it wiil have something to debounce.